# Pop Up to enter credentials

Tags: sharepoint, popup

When I open my SharePoint site collection everytime I am getting the pop up to enter the credential. How I can get rid off this. I checked in the alternate access mapping but I couldnt figure out anything difference,as the internal URL and external URL s are same. Can anyone help me regarding this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open internet explorer -> tools -> internet options -> security 
Choose internet 
Click on custom level and opt automatic logon in only intranet zone (it comes under user authentication)

Answer (score 2):

Open Internet Explorer, Internet Options, Security.
Choose Intranet and add your site to the intranet sites. 
Click on Custom Level and make sure that (in the end of the list) automatic logon in the intranet zone is selected.